# NV21 to Bitmap on Android, Very dark image, grayscale, or yellow tint?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, argb

I have been looking at converting the NV21 byte[] that I get from onPreviewFrame(). I have searched the forums and google for various solutions. I have tried RenderScripts and some other code examples. Some of them give me an image with a yellow tint, some give me an image with red and blue flipped (after I flip it back in the code, I get yellow tint back), some give me strange color features all throughout the image (almost like a negative), some give me a grayscale image, some give me an image so dark you can't really make anything out.

Since I am the one typing the question, I realize I must be the idiot in the room so we will start with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826709/yuv-nv21-image-convertion-to-bitmap). This particular solution gives me a very dark image, but I am not cool enough to be able to comment yet. Has anyone tried this solution or has one that produces an image with the same quality as the original NV21 format?

I need either a valid ARGB byte[] or a valid Bitmap, I can modify my project to deal with either. Just for reference I have tried these (and a few others that are really just carbon copies of these):

[One solution I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509360/converting-camera-yuv-data-to-argb-with-renderscript) 
[Another solution I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276522/convert-nv21-byte-array-into-bitmap-readable-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to convert YUV from camera to Bitmap, here is something you can try:

```
// import android.renderscript.*
// RenderScript mRS;
// ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB mYuvToRGB;
// Allocation yuvPreviewAlloc;
// Allocation rgbOutputAlloc;

// Create RenderScript context, ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB and Allocations and keep reusing them.
if (NotInitialized) {
    mRS = RenderScript.create(this).
    mYuvToRGB = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(mRS, Element.YUV(mRS));    

    // Create a RS Allocation to hold NV21 data.
    Type.Builder tYuv = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.YUV(mRS));
    tYuv.setX(width).setY(height).setYuvFormat(android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21);
    yuvPreviewAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, tYuv.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT | Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT);

    // Create a RS Allocation to hold RGBA data.
    Type.Builder tRgb = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.RGBA_8888(mRS));
    tRgb.setX(width).tRgb(height);
    rgbOutputAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, tRgb.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    // Set input of ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB
    mYuvToRGB.setInput(yuvPreviewAlloc);
}

// Use rsPreviewSurface as one of the output surface from Camera API.
// You can refer to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/hdrviewfinder/HdrViewfinderActivity.java#L504
Surface rsPreviewSurface = yuvPreviewAlloc.getSurface();
...

// Whenever a new frame is available
// Update the yuv Allocation with a new Camera buffer without any copy.
// You can refer to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/hdrviewfinder/ViewfinderProcessor.java#L109
yuvPreviewAlloc.ioReceive();
// The actual Yuv to Rgb conversion.
mYuvToRGB.forEach(rgbOutputAlloc);

// Copy the rgb Allocation to a Bitmap.
rgbOutputAlloc.copyTo(mBitmap);

// continue processing mBitmap.
...
```

Comment: You may also want to play with "YUV_420_888" and "YV12", in case of camera buffer is not "NV21".

Comment: I am trying this out, and I get and error that I haven't seen before: "E/RenderScript: YuvToRGB executed without data, skipping" each preview frame. I tried adding the "yuvPreviewAlloc.copyFrom(data);" just to be sure it wasn't something like that. Anyone come across this?

Comment: This error message usually means that the yuvPreviewAlloc Allocation didn't get any data from camera API. Please double check 1. if rsPreviewSurface is correctly configured as a Camera output surface. 2. If the ioReceive is invoked. 3. make sure you are using "import android.renderscript.*", since USAGE_IO_INPUT does not work with RenderScript support lib (import android.support.v8.renderscript). I also added some comments to the code to point you to some code reference for the setup.

Answer (score 1):

When using ScriptIntrinsics I highly recommend to update to at least JellyBean 4.3 or higher (API18). Things are much easier to use than in JB 4.2 (API 17).

ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB is not as complicated as it seems.
Especially you don´t need  Type.Builder objects.
Camera preview format *must* be NV21 !

in the onCreate()... method create the RenderScript object and the Intrinsic:

```
mRS = RenderScript.create(this);
mYuvToRGB = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(mRS, Element.U8_4(mRS));
```

With your cameraPreviewWidth and cameraPreviewHeight calculate the
length of the camera data byte array:

```
int yuvDatalength = cameraPreviewWidth*cameraPreviewHeight*3/2 ;  // this is 12 bit per pixel
```

You need a bitmap for output:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraPreviewWidth, cameraPreviewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Then you create the input and output allocations (here are the changes in API18+)

```
yuvPreviewAlloc = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.U8(mRS),  yuvDatalength);

rgbOutputAlloc =  Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, mBitmap);  // this simple !
```

and set the script-input to the input allocation

```
mYuvToRGB.setInput(yuvPreviewAlloc);  // this has to be done only once !
```

In the camera loop (whenever a new frame is avaliable), copy the NV21 byte-array (data[]) to the yuvPreviewAlloc, execute the script and copy result to bitmap:

```
yuvPreviewAlloc.copyFrom(data);  // or yuvPreviewAlloc.copyFromUnchecked(data);

mYuvToRGB.forEach(rgbOutputAlloc);

rgbOutputAlloc.copyTo(mBitmap);
```

For example: on Nexus 7 (2013, JellyBean 4.3) a full HD (1920x1080) camera preview conversion takes about 7 ms.

Comment: This does work and it works well! In the end I needed to do some additional work inside the render script anyway to keep my processing to a minimum. So, I had to write a custom render script (which took a while to figure out). I did find a lot of useful information in the Renderscript book (I got it on Amazon).

Comment: Note that **ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB** is wrong for camera frames, because these functions use the *video* [BT.610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion) color space (where **Y** is in range `[16…235]`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a different method working (one that was previously linked) by using the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=823). But that was giving the Red/Blue color flip. So, I just rearranged the U and V lines and all was ok. This is not as fast as a RenderScript though. It would be good to have a RenderScript that functioned properly. Here is the code:

```
static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0) y = 0;
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128; //Just changed the order
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128; //It was originally v then u
            }

            int y1192 = 1192 * y;
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

            if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
            if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
            if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

            rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
        }
    }
}
```

Any one have a RenderScript that doesn't have color tint and or flip problems?

Comment: `libyuv` can perform this conversion rather efficiently. In my experiments, this is faster on NEON that with renderscript, but it may depend on the device. One of the factors is that renderscript requires copying memory to GPU and back.