# Custom byteArray data to WebRTC videoTrack

Tags: android, android-camera, webrtc, android-vision, apprtcdemo

I need to use [WebRTC](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo) for android to send specific cropped(face) video to the videoChannel. I was able manipulate [Camera1Session](https://wing1.cs.ucla.edu/gitlab/tan/webrtc/blob/3d7a5007a72134ca8c066d9a3be52ef052e75b85/webrtc/api/android/java/src/org/webrtc/Camera1Session.java) class of WebRTC to get the face cropped. Right now I am setting it to an ImageView.
`listenForBytebufferFrames()` of `Camera1Session.java`

```
private void listenForBytebufferFrames() {
    this.camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera callbackCamera) {
            Camera1Session.this.checkIsOnCameraThread();
            if(callbackCamera != Camera1Session.this.camera) {
                Logging.e("Camera1Session", "Callback from a different camera. This should never happen.");
            } else if(Camera1Session.this.state != Camera1Session.SessionState.RUNNING) {
                Logging.d("Camera1Session", "Bytebuffer frame captured but camera is no longer running.");
            } else {
                mFrameProcessor.setNextFrame(data, callbackCamera);
                long captureTimeNs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                if(!Camera1Session.this.firstFrameReported) {
                    int startTimeMs = (int)TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - Camera1Session.this.constructionTimeNs);
                    Camera1Session.camera1StartTimeMsHistogram.addSample(startTimeMs);
                    Camera1Session.this.firstFrameReported = true;
                }

                ByteBuffer byteBuffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                Frame outputFrame = new Frame.Builder()
                        .setImageData(byteBuffer1,
                                Camera1Session.this.captureFormat.width,
                                Camera1Session.this.captureFormat.height,
                                ImageFormat.NV21)
                        .setTimestampMillis(mFrameProcessor.mPendingTimeMillis)
                        .setId(mFrameProcessor.mPendingFrameId)
                        .setRotation(3)
                        .build();
                int w = outputFrame.getMetadata().getWidth();
                int h = outputFrame.getMetadata().getHeight();
                SparseArray<Face> detectedFaces = mDetector.detect(outputFrame);
                if (detectedFaces.size() > 0) {

                    Face face = detectedFaces.valueAt(0);
                    ByteBuffer byteBufferRaw = outputFrame.getGrayscaleImageData();
                    byte[] byteBuffer = byteBufferRaw.array();
                    YuvImage yuvimage  = new YuvImage(byteBuffer, ImageFormat.NV21, w, h, null);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    //My crop logic to get face co-ordinates

                    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), 80, baos);
                    final byte[] jpegArray = baos.toByteArray();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length);

                    Activity currentActivity = getActivity();
                    if (currentActivity instanceof CallActivity) {
                        ((CallActivity) currentActivity).setBitmapToImageView(bitmap); //face on ImageView is set just fine
                    }
                    Camera1Session.this.events.onByteBufferFrameCaptured(Camera1Session.this, data, Camera1Session.this.captureFormat.width, Camera1Session.this.captureFormat.height, Camera1Session.this.getFrameOrientation(), captureTimeNs);
                    Camera1Session.this.camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
                } else {
                    Camera1Session.this.events.onByteBufferFrameCaptured(Camera1Session.this, data, Camera1Session.this.captureFormat.width, Camera1Session.this.captureFormat.height, Camera1Session.this.getFrameOrientation(), captureTimeNs);
                    Camera1Session.this.camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

`jpegArray` is the final byteArray that I need to stream via `WebRTC`, which I tried with something like this:

```
Camera1Session.this.events.onByteBufferFrameCaptured(Camera1Session.this, jpegArray, (int) face.getWidth(), (int) face.getHeight(), Camera1Session.this.getFrameOrientation(), captureTimeNs);
Camera1Session.this.camera.addCallbackBuffer(jpegArray);
```

Setting them up like this gives me following error:

```
../../webrtc/sdk/android/src/jni/androidvideotracksource.cc line 82
Check failed: length >= width * height + 2 * uv_width * ((height + 1) / 2) (2630 vs. 460800)
```

Which I assume is because `androidvideotracksource` does not get the same length of `byteArray` that it expects, since the frame is cropped now.
Could someone point me in the direction of how to achieve it? Is this the correct way/place to manipulate the data and feed into the `videoTrack`?

**Edit:**`bitmap` of byteArray `data` does not give me a camera preview on `ImageView`, unlike byteArray `jpegArray`. Maybe because they are packed differently?

Comment: Re: *bitmap of byteArray data does not give me a camera preview on ImageView* - how do you create a bitmap from NV21 data?

Comment: `yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), 80, baos);` does that to byteArray. I get a bitmap from `decodeByteArray`

Comment: So, `((CallActivity) currentActivity).setBitmapToImageView(bitmap)` does not work as expected, but `((CallActivity) currentActivity).setBitmapToImageView(jpegArray)` works?

Comment: Creating bitmap from `byte[] data` and setting it to imageView did not work, but from creating it from `byte[] jpegArray` did work. Anyways, I have posted my answer with the fix. Also in addition to it, I scaled to the expected dimension as your pointed out. I could not make `I420Frame` work however.

Comment: Here is the way to convert NV21 to bitmap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35852318/192373.

Comment: Right now my conversion takes 12-15 ms. I think it'll not make a significant difference?

Comment: Going through Jpeg it takes 12 ms? Actually, you should not do all this image processing on the UI thread, to begin with.

Comment: Just checked this. Going through jpeg takes 5-10ms, and `scale()` + `getNV21()` takes me 50-70ms. None of these happen on UI thread. I go back to UI thread only inside `setBitmapToImageView(bitmap);`

Comment: 50-70ms could be improved with renderscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was definitely a problem of how the original `byte[] data` was packed and the way `byte[] jpegArray` was packed. Changing the way of packing this and scaling it as AlexCohn suggested worked for me. I found help from [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960247/convert-bitmap-array-to-yuv-ycbcr-nv21) on StackOverflow on way to pack it. This is the code for it:

```
private byte[] getNV21(int left, int top, int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {
int [] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];
    scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, left, top, inputWidth, inputHeight);
    byte [] yuv = new byte[inputWidth*inputHeight*3/2];
    encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);
    scaled.recycle();
    return yuv;
}

private void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    int yIndex = 0;
    int uvIndex = frameSize;

    int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
            R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

            // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
            Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
            U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
            //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
            //    pixel AND every other scanline.
            yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
            if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
            }

            index ++;
        }
    }
}`
```

I pass this `byte[] data` to `onByteBufferFrameCaptured` and `callback`:

```
Camera1Session.this.events.onByteBufferFrameCaptured(
                            Camera1Session.this,
                            data,
                            w,
                            h,
                            Camera1Session.this.getFrameOrientation(),
                            captureTimeNs);
Camera1Session.this.camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
```

Prior to this, I had to scale the bitmap which is pretty straight forward:

```
int width = bitmapToScale.getWidth();
int height = bitmapToScale.getHeight();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(newWidth / width, newHeight / height);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapToScale, 0, 0, bitmapToScale.getWidth(), bitmapToScale.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you do with the result of `getNV21()`.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can we use WebRTC's Datachannel to exchang custom data ie cropped face "image" in your case and do the respective calculation at receiving end using any third party library ie OpenGL etc? Reason I am suggesting is that the WebRTC Video feed received from channel is a stream in real time not a bytearray . WebRTC Video by its inherent architecture isn't meant to crop video at other hand. If we want to crop or augment video we have to use any ar library to fulfill this job.

We can always leverage WebRTC's Data channel to exchange customized data. Using Video channel for the same is not recommended because it's real time stream not the bytearray.Please revert in case of any concern.

Comment: Is `DataChannel` enough to support continuous stream of large `byteArray`?

Comment: No.In overlay or in any sort augmentation object recognition is must. For that purpose one party can exchange image using webrtc data channel with another party along with different other relevant coordinates i.e.  cropping details w.r.t. image. At receiving party context calculation can be done to display overlay of cropped face ,live feed can be shown using openGL.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC in particular and video streaming in general presumes that the video has fixed dimensions. If you want to crop the detected face, your options are either to have pad the cropped image with e.g. black pixels (WebRTC does not use transparency), and crop the video on the receiver side, or, if you don't have control over the receiver, [resize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) the cropped region to fill the expected `width * height` frame (you should also keep the expected aspect ratio).

Note that JPEG compress/decompress that you use to crop the original is far from efficient. Some other options can be found in *[Image crop and resize in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602465/image-crop-and-resize-in-android)*.

Comment: Bandwidth consumption in case of a scaled or padded data would be same as that of a video call, no? Also, face crop on receive would be very tedious in case of a low light video if padded(it would also double the computation in my case). Scaling would disrupt aspect ratio of the face itself. Anyway I could append the face aspect ratio within `I420Frame`?

Comment: Bandwidth overhead of constant padding (black is not necessary) is minimal, thanks to video compression. Scaling (zoom in) of a bitmap does not add much to bandwidth for the same reason. I could not understand what you mean by 'disrupt aspect ratio'. Yes, you can work within I420Frame.